# Stop Xbox Music app in Windows 8.1 from downloading Album Art for Music

Tags: windows, xbox

My internet connection is slow and I like to listen to music while I do work on my PC. But while I listen to music on Xbox Music app on Windows 8.1 the album art gets automatically downloaded and is displayed and makes my internet connection even more slow.
I would like to Xbox Music app on Windows 8.1 from downloading album art.

The App I am referring to is [this app.](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-in/app/music/16db93bf-8748-449a-96ba-e9ed3a5f872d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open Xbox Music app
- Move cursor to upper-right corner and move down or swipe in from
  right edge to Access Charms & Select Settings.
- Select Preferences
- Look for Media Info: Automatically retrieve and update album art and 
  metadata. Turn the option OFF.

I hope this helps.